# String to String with Precision

Tags: c#, string

Perhaps a trivial question, but i'm drawing a blank.

I have something like:

```
public class Foo
{
        private string _variableValue;
        public string VariableValue
        {
            get
            {
                return _variableValue;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == _variableValue) return;
                _variableValue = value;
            }
        }

        public int Precision { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, `VariableValue` holds a double value. I store a decimal precision number in `Precision`. How can I have `VariableValue` `Get` return itself but formatted `Precision` decimal places?

*Example:* `VariableValue` is "10.12345", `Precision` is `2`:
`VariableValue` should be `10.12`

*Example(2)*: `VariableValue` is "10", `Precision` is `5`:
`VariableValue` should be `10.00000`

Comment: Can you explain your question better, please?

Comment: By parsing the string as double, rounding it to the required number of decimals and returning it as string.

Comment: If you are "holding" a `double` value in `VariableValue`, why is it a `string`?

Comment: I would translate the string to a double, and expose the value as a double. However, if that's not viable, you can parse for the decimal point and truncate based on its position relative to total string length.

Comment: @Michael I was thinking that was more than likely the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean `_variableValue` is a double? In that case:

```
public class Foo
{
    private double _variableValue;
    public string VariableValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _variableValue.ToString("N" + Precision);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == _variableValue.ToString()) return;
            Double.TryParse(value, _variableValue); // in case of non-numerics
        }
    }

    public int Precision { get; set; }
}
```

If `_variableValue' is not a double... then its a bit weirder:

```
public class Foo
{
    private string _variableValue;
    public string VariableValue
    {
        get
        {
            double doubleValue;
            Double.TryParse(_variableValue, out doubleValue); // in the case of non-numerics
            return doubleValue.ToString("N" + Precision);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == _variableValue) return;
            _variableValue = value;
        }
    }

    public int Precision { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: didn't know it was quite that simple

Comment: _variableValue is NOT a double. @Jonesy

Comment: does it change anything if you take the first approach though...?

Comment: @gleng I edited the answer: just do a quick conversion before returning the value.

Comment: @Vlad Yeah, I was thinking that would probably be the best approach as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Jonesy It's possible that `VariableValue` could have non-numeric data in it. TryParse seems like the only real way to do it, because if it returns false I know it has invalid data in it.